# what is the utility to use apache kafka with logstash?

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, logstash

I’m looking forward to gather in real time the flux of logs from a specific web application in order to get an overview of my infrastructure’s performance. as tools I’ll use Elk rather than Splunk , due to some articles, they extremely recommend to use Kafka with logstash but until now I dunno the purpose of that, In fact, my main purpose is to set the basics modules for the app so I have to get a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify this deployment, the web server backend could log directly to Kafka.

If you have logs files instead, you can use [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/kafka-output.html) or Fluentd's Kafka output rather than Logstash.

Logstash would essentially be an aggregator that can performs actions between `inputs -> filters -> outputs`

Kafka is an [option as an output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-kafka.html), rather than typically only Elasticsearch.

The problem I see with Logstash + Filebeat is that you must restart all the processes and configurations to add an input event source similar to SplunkForwarder, and you cannot configure unique topics per input very easily without some crazy tagging logic in the Logstash config. The more scalable solution, I think would be having the origin of the data configuring which Kafka topic it writes into.

The main reason why Kafka (was) recommended was before [Persistent Queues](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/persistent-queues.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm wondering if the web server backend could log directly into Logstah input without any intermediate, if yes, is it the best solution to manage and process the logs received from the applications in real - time?

Comment: Logstash should be ran on its own server and with at least 6G java heap space for a production deployment. You can also install multiple logstashs as a cluster... But you'll need "something" sending data to it. Filebeat & Packetbeat could be running on the web server. Kafka can also send data into Logstash, in case you are under the impression it's one or the other

Comment: Actually, I  read 400 MB of data from a CSV file with Logstash and sent all the events to Elasticsearch with only 1 G  of java heap, 6 GO isn't  a huge amount of stock even to read from a small file?according to your  response,  sending logs from the web server to Logstash input will need  an intermediate in my case  I  would  deploy Kafka and  I  hope  that it's the  best solution.thank you very much for  your  help

Comment: How  can I install multiple  logstashs as a cluster ?

Comment: If you only have one data source, 1G can be enough, but you'll eventually have more data, so more memory upfront will be a good idea. Kafka and Zookeeper memory similarly needs to be around those amounts https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/deploying-and-scaling.html

Comment: thanks  you for your precious help ,I'm very appreciated